# selection and iteration

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a c++ program where you can choose which operation you want to make and then choose the quantity of numbers to calculate the result. And I want to use a `getchar` function, but I cannot figure it out.
How do you even make int so that it behaves like a variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
/*char a_char;
a_char=getchar();
cout<<a_char;*/

  int opcode;
  int a, b;
  int result;

  printf("Program for Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division\n");
  printf("Enter Your Choice: 1 - Add, 2 - Sub, 3 - Mul, 4 - Div: ");
  scanf("%d", &opcode);
  printf("Enter First Number:"); 
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Enter Second Number:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  switch(opcode)
  {
  case 1:
        result = a + b;
        printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, result);
        break;
  case 2:
        result = a - b;
        printf("%d - %d = %d", a, b, result);
        break;
  case 3:
        result = a * b;
        printf("%d * %d = %d", a, b, result);
        break;
  case 4:
        result = a / b;
        printf("%d / %d = %d\n%d %% %d = %d", a, b, result, a, b, a % b);
        break;
  }

}
```

Comment: standard warning, `default` case missing. also, dont mix `C` and `C++` . This looks like `c` [`scanf()`, `printf()`]

Comment: `int main() { char a; a = getchar(); std::cout << a << std::endl; }` works as expected: It reads a character (and the "enter" key) and prints out that character.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your intent? There are 3 inputs from the user (`opcode`,`a` and `b`). Which one do you want to be a `char`? All of them? This implies that the user cannot input more than 1-digit value or you want an __array__ of `char` (e.g., `12` as `1` char + `2` char) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that you want to input the operation code via `getchar`, it would look something like this:

```
opcode = getchar();
```

and then in your `switch` you encase the values in singular quotes:

```
case '1':
....
case '2':
.... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve what you exactly need.

You can replace the following line,

```
scanf("%d", &opcode);
```

as

```
opcode=getchar();
opcode = opcode-'0';
```

Since getchar will give you ASCII Code. so you need to convert to integer value so you need to subtract '0'.

It is logic: '0' is 48 :)